# BulkFileChanger command-line issue

Tags: command-line, date-modified, touch

My test on [BulkFileChanger v1.65](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bulk_file_changer.html): In command-line, parameter /cfg doesn't work. So, the command-line can be ran with default cfg only.

For Example, the command 
`bulkfilechanger.exe /cfg "myconfig.cfg" /ChangeTimeAttr "C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\sample\2" "*" 10 0 /LogFile`
doesn't work. I did anywhere mistake?

Comment: What if you specify the full path to `myconfig.cfg`?

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski: It's Same. No error in cmd and log file!

Comment: Anybody test it?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of testing, I found the solution:

The configuration file (*.cfg) **must be clearly** indicated with its location path.

```
BulkFileChanger /cfg BulkTest.cfg
```

Does not work, however

```
BulkFileChanger /cfg C:\Test\BulkTest.cfg
```

Works!

---

But there is another problem that makes finding the problem very difficult.

If we start from the idea we have:

```
C:\Test\BulkFileChanger.exe (139 KB)

C:\Test\BulkTest.cfg (2 KB)
```

And we run the wrong command (path of the cfg-file is missing):

```
C:\Test\BulkFileChanger.exe /cfg BulkTest.cfg
```

This destroys the contents of the cfg-file!

```
C:\Test\BulkTest.cfg (0 KB)
```

And "BulkTest.cfg" will no longer work ! **It must be recreated**.

You must give the following command in one of these forms:

```
C:\Test\BulkFileChanger.exe /cfg C:\Test\BulkTest.cfg

BulkFileChanger.exe /cfg C:\Test\BulkTest.cfg

BulkFileChanger /cfg C:\Test\BulkTest.cfg

BulkFileChanger.exe /cfg .\BulkTest.cfg
```

In this last example `.\` will tell you the current directory, and it works !

During your tests, it would be a precaution to save your CFG files before you make your testing.

Good day.